# An important lesson learned today...

Tags: portable-recorder

I'm a contributive citizen of Los Angeles County and I support a government run for all it's people.

That's why I left my house at 6:00 AM this morning because I had a 7:30 AM jury duty call at the downtown courthouse. I didn't want to be late.

After grabbing a quick coffee, I make my way down Sunset Blv. anticipating the traffic I was inevitably going to hit. I made it to the Disney Concert Hall in about 10 minutes.

Walking down the street to the courthouse it suddenly dawned on me. It was a ton of bricks from out of nowhere. How could I have been that stupid...

There's a line already forming in front of the courthouse. They don't let the new jurors in until 7:30 AM. I glance at my watch; it's 6:45.

The first thing that happened right in front of me was like grains of salt being poured into an open wound: the traffic ceased and there was seemingly no wash of a freeway I could hear and suddenly a humongous flock of pigeons decide to take off simultaneously not 5 feet in front of me on the street.

The next occurrence was like cayenne pepper in a paper cut: a jeep with a faulty A/C belt which was squeaking like a gerbil in heat pulled up and waited 7 feet in front of me at the red light for at least a minute and a half.

Then, the icing on the cake. This was like tabasco in a knife wound. A whole parade of LA construction equipment drove by - including a scooper with full-on tank treads on them.

And all this...

... and me without my H2n portable recorder... That's the important lesson I learned today. Bring your portable recorder EVERYWHERE.

Please forgive me, my fellow SSD members.

I have failed you...

How can I ever make it up to you?

Comment: Lol I get those pangs of guilt from time to time! Been dying to record a bunch of foxes that keep waking me up with truly blood curling cries most nights. Everyone they do it, it only lasts briefly but too quick for me to get out of my sleepy daze to record in time! :/ how's the h2n working out? Better internal mics/noisefloor than the h2? How fast to power up?

Comment: It's pretty nice. I haven't used it much actually but it's pretty much the same as the H2 as far as I remember. I wish I could have recorded the few intro speeches of the workers here... But then again, the security guards might not have let me in with a recorder anyway - taking photos or recording the trials is prohibited.

Comment: I've been chasing a train horn for weeks that way.  KILLS me every time that thing blows its horn and I'm not rolling.  it mocks me...

Comment: I did jury duty a while back.  wrote long blog posts about it.  here's one: http://thesoundmyheadmakes.blogspot.com/2009/07/jury-duty-one-spin-through-system-part.html

Comment: @Rene That's an awesome overview. I got called but the time I walked up to the 8th floor of the courthouse they had already resolved the case so I went back to the waiting room. Otherwise, I'm done for a year.

Answer (score 2):

You might be a sound recordist..

Comment: Hah! For sure!!

Answer (score 2):

Thats tough man, the guilt you might feel.  So you're not a god afterall.